# java recursion, finding occurrence of target in string

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to get more familiar with recursion in java. I am trying to count number of times character occurs in a given string.

```
public class apptest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        apptest c = new apptest();
        String input = "aaa";
        char p = 'a';

        c.freq(input, p);
    }

    public int freq(String c, char p) {
        if (c.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (c.charAt(0) == p) {

            return 1 + freq(c.substring(1, c.length()), p);
        } else
            return freq(c.substring(1, c.length()), p);
    }
}
```

I am not getting any output. and completely confused on how to solve a problem like this. I looked online and found the `freq(c.substring(1, c.length()),p);` part but going through the code it doesn't make sense.. seems like on every pass its still going to deal with 'aa' and not necessarily shrink it.. what am I not seeing?

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks good, but you're not getting output because you're not printing it!

Simply add a `System.out.println(...)` to your main method.

```
System.out.println("Frequency is: " + c.freq(input, p));
```

Comment: LOL OMG THANKS.. i was adding println inside the freq method and I kept seeing multiple println's so I thought it was wrong...BUT THANK YOU

Comment: @user2556304: you're welcome! Were all problems so easy to solve. :)

Answer (score 1):

For this part:

> I looked online and found the freq(c.substring(1, c.length()),p); part but going through the code it doesn't make sense.. seems like on every pass its still going to deal with 'aa' and not necessarily shrink it.

The line `c.substring(1, c.length())` shrinks the String `c` so that what gets passed into the recursive call has one less character to process and thus, helping the recursive call to eventually reach the termination condition of `c.length() == 0`.  So, it is safe to assume that `freq` method's implementation is correct.

Comment: @Downvoters: please, read through the question before voting. OP asked two questions, and since Hover already answered one I won't repeat that.

Comment: I'll 1+ since you're answering the secondary question that I missed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks, that's one for sportsmanship badge:) I've got 3 -1's but the voters all removed those. +1 for you too.

Comment: Your answer does not make sense.  Whats the use of recursion if input is not reducing with every call.  Read your answer and see if it make any sense.  If he uses same string for each recursive call, then, when it will terminate...let me guess ...with "StackOverflow"?

Comment: @WandMaker: Ziyao Wei is right. It in fact does make sense for the secondary question.

Comment: @WandMaker I agree with Hovercraft Full Of Eels. The quote was from the OP.

Comment: @Hovercraft Really! Ziyao is indicating there is an issue with program, whereas only issue it has is it is missing SOP for output.  I ran the program, it has no issues except that.  What is the value of this answer ?  I am going to go with my downvote.

Comment: @WandMaker Who said an answer must solve a problem in the code? This answer replies to the question OP asked which is not "how" but is "why". Downvote if you want to, I simply have no right nor method to stop you, but I still think you misunderstood. BTW, perhaps my English is bad, but I did not intend to hint that there is a problem in the code.

Comment: @WandMaker: re `"Really! Ziyao is indicating there is an issue with program, whereas only issue it has is it is missing SOP for output. I ran the program, it has no issues except that. What is the value of this answer ? I am going to go with my downvote."` -- no he's not. He's just explaining why the line of code is correct. Please re-evaluate your thoughts here. I understand Ziyao's answer perfectly and it makes logical sense and *does* answer the secondary question. Please remove your down-vote because that's the only thing here that *doesn't* make sense.

Comment: I removed the downvote.  But his answer read like he is pointing out a mistake in the code "...so you are not using the same string in the recursive call." and which follows with thought "..okay, so do I need to pass same string...let me do it".  My objection is to the way it sounds.

Comment: @WandMaker That is to counter the statement "seems like on every pass its still going to deal with 'aa'". And if you can think of a better phrase please feel free to go ahead and improve the answer, especially since it is causing confusion on you.

Comment: @WandMaker and Ziyao Wei: answer edited to hopefully clarify things. WandMaker, please up-vote this answer to make up for the trouble you caused. :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks, that's very kind of you:)

Comment: I was still not happy with the explanation, so I have further edited it.